# Annual Stack Overflow Awards

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow should create it's own annual awards, like the Oscars, Tonys, Grammy, People's Choice, etc. Of course there'd be the top rep earner for the year, but I can easily think of other fun and meaningful awards for things like best answer and best question, and distinguish these from highest-voted question and answer. Also best edit, rookie of the year... I could go on.

One of the things Stack Overflow has been great at is designing incentives that encourage good behaviors, and I think this would fall right in there with the badge system. Award winners could even get a gold badge in addition to whatever trophy (real or virtual) we wanted to create.

Comment: Would these be selected by nominations too? Certain things like "best edit" can't be quantified, after all.

Comment: I think they'd have to be, but the devil is in the details... and there are a lot of details that would need to be worked out for this feature-request. For example, it'd be tempting to just use the same interface we do now for the community elections, but I think that would be a mistake. Nominations should be selective, and a straight-up vote probably should only be an influence, rather than the final decision. But I think this has enough potential to be worth the trouble.

Comment: Tough to implement.  What makes these awards work is that they are not just popularity contents.  Winners are picked by a secret cabal of industry insiders.

Comment: `Spoiler alert!` And the winner is .... Jon Skeet!

Answer (score 10):

I like this idea.

I say we test it: **post your nominations for "Best Edit of 2014" in the comments below this post.**

I don't have any trophies, but I'll pledge to send **a waffle** to the editor behind the top-voted edit, if I can convince them to give up their address.

[image]

If it works, maybe we can find a way to **bronze** a waffle. Or think of better trophy ideas.

Comment: What gave me the idea for the feature was my series of edits to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977204/translated-c-sharp-tictactoe-game-to-vb-net-and-the-game-state-is-not-fully-cle

Comment: Ah, so it was just a roundabout way of tooting your own horn all along... ;)

Comment: Of course. What else would it be :P

Comment: And also consider the rising stars...

Comment: @Avinash Raj: I think that is covered by "rookie of the year" in the question.

Comment: This man makes exceptionally good waffles. The winner will be fortunate indeed.